# C++ - segmentation fault when inheritance

Tags: c++, qt

I got very strange behaviour with my very simple example which crashes when i use inheritance (`class NapanaApplication : public QGuiApplication`), but doesn't crash and works properly when using directly `QGuiApplication`.

The code is exactly as seen below, the `NapanaApplication` doesn't do anything, just inherits from `QGuiApplication`.

What's wrong?

**SOLVED:** I found a reason. It is because the `QGuiApplication` takes the `argc` as reference, but the `NapanaApplication` constructor doesn't. It doesn't generate any error, but it causes that the `QGuiApplication` operated with some temporary `argc` variable instead of the one from `main`.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "napanaapplication.h"
#include "napanawindow.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    /*NapanaApplication app(argc, argv);*/ // segmentation fault

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv); // no error        

    NapanaWindow win;

    win.resize(800, 600);
    win.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**napanaapplication.h**

```
#ifndef NAPANAAPPLICATION_H
#define NAPANAAPPLICATION_H

#include <QGuiApplication>

class NapanaApplication : public QGuiApplication
{

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit NapanaApplication(int argc, char* argv[]);
signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // NAPANAAPPLICATION_H
```

**napanapplication.c**

```
#include "napanaapplication.h"

NapanaApplication::NapanaApplication(int argc, char* argv[]) : QGuiApplication(argc, argv) {}
```

**Output from debugger: it crashes when `strlen` is called in `QString::fromLocal8Bit`.** The `char*` pointer on which the `strlen` is called has value `0x21`, i don't understand why, it should be probably something from `argv`.

```
0   strlen  /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so    106 0x7ffff65c0aea  
1   QString::fromLocal8Bit  qstring.h   534 0x7ffff7142c11  
2   QCoreApplication::arguments qcoreapplication.cpp    2254    0x7ffff738503d  
3   sm_performSaveYourself  qxcbsessionmanager.cpp  188 0x7ffff05f5e3a  
4   sm_saveYourselfCallback qxcbsessionmanager.cpp  171 0x7ffff05f5cc9  
5   _SmcProcessMessage          0x7ffff014ad37  
6   IceProcessMessages          0x7fffeff3b8c7  
7   QSmSocketReceiver::socketActivated  qxcbsessionmanager.cpp  322 0x7ffff05f67e0  
8   QSmSocketReceiver::qt_static_metacall   qxcbsessionmanager.moc  68  0x7ffff05f6f88  
9   QMetaObject::activate   qobject.cpp 3718    0x7ffff73c097e  
10  QMetaObject::activate   qobject.cpp 3583    0x7ffff73c016c  
11  QSocketNotifier::activated  moc_qsocketnotifier.cpp 134 0x7ffff7458376  
12  QSocketNotifier::event  qsocketnotifier.cpp 296 0x7ffff73cb4db  
13  QCoreApplicationPrivate::notify_helper  qcoreapplication.cpp    1093    0x7ffff7382872  
14  QCoreApplication::notify    qcoreapplication.cpp    1038    0x7ffff7382554  
15  QGuiApplication::notify qguiapplication.cpp 1537    0x7ffff77f3076  
16  QCoreApplication::notifyInternal    qcoreapplication.cpp    965 0x7ffff738245e  
17  QCoreApplication::sendEvent qcoreapplication.h  224 0x7ffff7386087  
18  socketNotifierSourceDispatch    qeventdispatcher_glib.cpp   101 0x7ffff73f6afe  
19  g_main_context_dispatch         0x7ffff4f8dbd4  
20  ??          0x7ffff4f8de18  
21  g_main_context_iteration            0x7ffff4f8debc  
22  QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents qeventdispatcher_glib.cpp   418 0x7ffff73f7799  
23  QPAEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents   qeventdispatcher_glib.cpp   115 0x7ffff0648906  
24  QEventLoop::processEvents   qeventloop.cpp  128 0x7ffff737f0b2  
25  QEventLoop::exec    qeventloop.cpp  204 0x7ffff737f373  
26  QCoreApplication::exec  qcoreapplication.cpp    1229    0x7ffff7382b36  
27  QGuiApplication::exec   qguiapplication.cpp 1528    0x7ffff77f3026  
28  main    main.cpp    13  0x40275a
```

Comment: Crashes with what error?

Comment: @Surt: segmentation fault (Signal SIGSEGV)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Note the signature of QGuiApplication](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html):

```
QGuiApplication(int & argc, char ** argv)
```

Your function has `int argc` instead. I think you're causing a segfault when the integer value is then treated as a reference by the parent class constructor.

Comment: Oooo. That would do it. Bad number leads to wrong number of arguments, leads to `strlen` on unterminated char array.

Comment: @user4581301 Kinda weird that it's only happening when you kick off the event loop via `app.exec()`, though? I guess Qt isn't checking some of the args before then.

Comment: i looked into source code and it is because Qt stores the argc as reference too, they initialize it in constructor QtConstructor(int& argcc) : argc(argcc). If they store it as normal int, nothing will happen.