# After initializing class member app crashes with SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault

I have Qt application with Application class:

```
class Application : public QApplication {
public:
    Application(int argc, char** argv);
    ~Application();
};
```

everything works fine until I add

```
private:
    const QString NAME = "QtImageViewer";
```

after that app crashes 9 of 10 times when I try to run it

main looks like

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Application app(argc, argv);
    app.setApplicationName("QtImageViewer");

    MainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.show();

    return (app.exec());
}
```

I'd like to know what's wrong because I have no idea.

Edit:
[GDB backtrace](http://pastebin.com/sMhRCnr6)
[Valgrind](http://pastebin.com/eTegVm7x)

Comment: must be something else. The line you added should work fine.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yea, that's what I'm telling myself, h/e without that line, everything works fine, even when I run debug, breakpoint (sigsegv) is at app.exec() which is after logic of my program

Comment: maybe post the code of your application if it's not too big.

Comment: My educated guess: somewhere in the code you haven't shown, there's a heap corruption bug. It used to go unnoticed, but now you've effectively added a heap deallocation to `~Application` (where `NAME` is being destroyed), which happens to hit the corrupted area of the heap.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre https://github.com/hladik-dan/QtImageViewer here you go, not too big, but no small either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it, same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33271398/c-segmentation-fault-when-inheritance).

My Application class constructor signature is `Application(int argc, char** argv);` but QApplication has `QApplication(int &argc, char **argv)`

Changed `Application(int argc, char** argv);` to `Application(int& argc, char** argv);` and everything works.

Thanks to all for help.

Comment: An additional information that came into my mind that might be helpful for you in future. It is not problem with Qt itself, but with all libraries you use that also provided the possibility to pass or request objects of the std library you always need to take care that all libraries you use are linked against the same (or binary compatible) std library as your application. Especially under windows this would be a problem if Qt was build for a different VisualStudio version then you use for your application. Under linux that is less a problem, because you normally relay on the package manager.

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment, but I don't have enough reputation at the time of this writing. For the record, I cloned your repository you linked to. I notice you don't seem to be using Qt Creator but are probably just using `cmake`. My Qt 5 installation isn't where yours is, so I just threw everything into Qt Creator and built and ran the project from there.

The program runs and closes just fine, even with the change you suggest breaks it for you. (Built and run on Ubuntu 16 with Qt 5.5, g++ 5.4.0.)

Additionally, I may be misunderstanding Igor's comment, but since `Application` is made on the stack, no additional heap deallocation is introduced to `~Application()`.

Comment: Your answer made me think. After all it seems that my code is fine. I'm using arch linux and I recently had update for Qt libs and looks like something is broken there. Just tested app at VirualBox (Kubuntu 16.04) and everything works fine.

Comment: That the given code runs fine on your or another system does not mean that there is not problem. Double freed memory, continue using already freed objects, ... would not necessarily lead into an immediate fail. Depending on the used operating system and the linked library versions or the compiler that was used for building those libraries or the application itself,  you would have in a slightly different usage of the memory, those differences can _hide_ such problems on one setup and make them _visible_  in another one. So the problem could still be in the code of the OP. @Itha255

Comment: @Itha255 You do indeed delete `m_pixmapItem`, but I noticed that there are others you don't delete (not doing this is just leaking--also bad, but not the source of your segfault, since you still own that memory up until program termination). For example, you have `m_scene = new QGraphicsScene();` in `image.cpp` with no corresponding delete. The same holds for `m_toolBar = new ToolBar();` in `main_window.cpp`.

Comment: @orphen Yes I do know that. Because I'm not really sure what Qt frees itself therefore I free only those Valgrind tells me about.

Comment: Okay, understood. We'd have to read the documentation for the Qt classes you use to see if Qt assumes responsibility for any components you may hand off to it. On another note, can you by chance provide the Valgrind stacktrace, perhaps as an edit to your original question?

Comment: @Itha255 You always need to know how the library you use does memory management, e.g. you need to check if the library takes over responsibility for an object if you pass its pointer to a function or not and in which order you have to delete object. Qt has a complex internal memory handling [Implicit Sharing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html), and iirc for certain Qt objects like `QPixmap` you should not use `new`, but I haven't used Qt for a long time now so I don't know what has change.

Comment: @t.niese Thx, I'll definitely take a closer look on that.

Comment: @Itha255 But just to be clear. I don't say that your code is necessarily wrong, it for sure could just be a problem with your Arch setup. But it is important to know that if the error does not occur on another system does not mean that the problem is gone.